# A question in Subspaces in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Looking for some help with the following question. I have begun to understand the concept of subspaces, but not sure how to deal with transverse matrices.

So I need to determine which of the subsets of $M_n(\Bbb R)$ are actually subspaces:

1) $ U = \{A \in M_n\Bbb (R) : A^t = A\}$,
2) $ U = \{A \in M_n\Bbb (R) : A^t = -A\}$,
3) $ U = \{A \in M_n\Bbb (R) : A^t \neq A\}$.

Comment: The same rules apply, except your "vectors" are now matrices.

Comment: so a vector must be not empty, closed under addition and closed under multiplication

Comment: Not a vector - a vector **space** must satisfy those axioms from your previous question.

Comment: oh the rules I put in my question?

Comment: if so then I do not know how to proceed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The **characterization of a subspace** is that for all $A,B \in U$ and scalars $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb R$ you have that
>   $$\alpha A+\beta B\in U. $$

Let us consider $U_1$ which I will solve so you can get the basic understanding. By definition of $U_1$, matrices $A,B\in U_1$ satisfy $A^\intercal = A$ and $B^\intercal=B$. Now consider the linear combination
$$\alpha A + \beta B = \alpha A^\intercal + \beta B^\intercal = (\alpha A + \beta B)^\intercal$$
by linearity of the transpose. Since $\alpha A + \beta B = (\alpha A + \beta B)^\intercal$ we have that $\alpha A + \beta B\in U_1$ and hence we conclude that $U_1$ is a subspace of $M_n (\mathbb R).$

**Hint for (2).** Apply similar reasoning and you get $$\alpha A + \beta B = \alpha (-A)^\intercal + \beta (-B)^\intercal = -(\alpha A + \beta B)^\intercal$$
so what can we conclude?

**Hint for (3).** Consider scalars $\alpha = \beta = 1$ and
$$A = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right]\quad B = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & -1\\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right] $$
which both do not equal their own transpose. Then you will see that $\alpha A + \beta B = (\alpha A + \beta B)^\intercal$, and hence what can we conclude?

Comment: is this for the first question

Comment: and thank you for your time

Comment: The characterization is something that works in general. However, I have solved the first problem for you, where I have named the subset $U_1$ for convenience.

Comment: This applies to **all** the questions. You just have to modify the arguments. I suggest you take some time to sketch out similar arguments, as well as find more examples in your text.

Comment: okay thank you both for helping

Comment: @Eff any hints for number 2?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For the first question test if, given $A=A^T$ and $B=B^T$ we have:
$$
(A+B)^T=A+B \quad \mbox{and}\quad (cA)^T=c(A^T)
$$